# Why do my python sklearn logistic regression results differ from this example?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, intercept

I found following example mentioned at wikipedia

[image: Example mentioned from wikipedia]

However, when I use sklearn my results are different.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import 
LogisticRegression
hours1=  [0.50,0.75,1.00, 
1.25,1.50,1.75,1.75,2.00,2.25, 
2.50,2.75,3.00,3.25,3.50,4.00,
4.25,4.50,
4.75,5.00,5.50]
len(hours1)
pass1=[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1]
len(pass1)

X_train=np.array([hours1])
y_train=np.array([pass1])
X_train.shape=(20,1)
y_train.shape=(20,)
clf= 
LogisticRegression(random_state=0).fit(X_train, 
y_train)
print("coef_ is", clf.coef_)
print("intercept_ is" ,clf.intercept_)

# my results are
coef_ is [[0.61126347]]
intercept_ is [-1.36550178]
```

Can someone help to explain how can I get the same result as shown on [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression).

Answer (score 3):

You need to optimize the model by tuning parameters.

- Since your dataset is small you need to  specified good algorithm to optimization.For small dataset `lbfgs` is a good choice.
- Another important parameter is `inverse of regularization strength`,which is `C` in sklearn.Default `C` value is 1.0 in sklearn.If you run a small test on different C values like this

For example

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

hours1=  [0.50,0.75,1.00, 
1.25,1.50,1.75,1.75,2.00,2.25, 
2.50,2.75,3.00,3.25,3.50,4.00,
4.25,4.50,
4.75,5.00,5.50]
len(hours1)
pass1=[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1]
len(pass1)

X_train=np.array([hours1])
y_train=np.array([pass1])
X_train.shape=(20,1)
y_train.shape=(20,)

param_grid = [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]
coef = []
intc = []
param = []
for p in param_grid: 
    clf = LogisticRegression(C=p,random_state=0,solver='lbfgs',fit_intercept=True)
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

    coef.append(clf.coef_[0])
    intc.append(clf.intercept_)
    param.append(p)

coef = np.array(coef)
intc = np.array(intc)

plt.plot(param, coef[:, 0], color='blue', marker='x', label='coefficient')
plt.plot(param, intc[:, 0], color='green',  marker='o', label='intercept')
plt.ylabel('intercept/coefficient')
plt.xlabel('C')
plt.legend(loc='right')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.show()
```

If you plot the intercept and coefficient over different C values,you can see you get the expected output when C=1000 or around that. 
[image]

now you can fit the model using `C as 1000( 1e3 == 1000)`

```
clf = LogisticRegression(C=1e3,random_state=0,solver='lbfgs',fit_intercept=True)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
print("coef_ is", clf.coef_)
print("intercept_ is" ,clf.intercept_)
```

```
#output 
 coef_ is [[1.50405093]]
 intercept_ is [-4.07616221]
```